# Detecting sprite Y coordinates

Tags: java, libgdx

The sprite is moving upward and I want it to be removed when touched. 
I am able to detect if the sprite is touched using the `X` coordinate, but not with the `Y` coordinate, when I use `Gdx.input.getY()` the lower I go the `Y` coordinate gets higher, basically it's reversed.

This is the code for the X coordinate detection:

```
if ( touched == true && touchX > sprite.getX() &&
     touchX < sprite.getX() + sprite.getWidth() ) {
    enemyIterator.remove();
    Pools.free(sprite);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To make it properly you should use your Viewport's or Camera's **unproject** method to convert your screen coordinates into world coordinates. Then use converted (unprojected) screen coordinates in conditions.

```
Vector2 unprojectedTouch = viewport.unproject(new Vector2(touchX, touchY));
//Vector3 unprojectedTouch = camera.unproject(new Vector3(touchX, touchY, 1));

if(touched==true && unprojectedTouch.x > sprite.getX() && unprojectedTouch.x < sprite.getX()+sprite.getWidth()){
      enemyIterator.remove();
      Pools.free(sprite);
}
```

The only difference between Viewport's and Camera's unproject methods that Viewport's unproject method calls Camera's unproject method inside by making z coordinate optional to make it easier to use for 2D usage.

See: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/viewport/Viewport.html#unproject-com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2-

Answer (score 0):

*Y is inverted...*
Your Y code should look like this (note te page.getHeight(), *page* is the *screen, canvas, document*... call it as you want.)

** Y origin is not the same for UI elements and Touch points **

```
  if(touched==true
       && touchY > page.getHeight() - sprite.getY() 
       && touchY < page.getHeight() - sprite.getY()+sprite.getHeight()){
                       enemyIterator.remove();
                       Pools.free(sprite);
    }**
```